# Benefit of putting vector on stack

Tags: c++

Is there any real performance benefit of worrying about putting `vector`s on the stack instead of the heap, since internally `vector` will put things on the heap anyway?

Comment: Yes, easier memory management for the developer, you do not need to think about deleting it.

Comment: In all fairness he is asking about "performance" gains, not convenience.

Comment: Probably not. The best way to know if something helps performance is to try in the closest possible conditions to the real use and when done developing check it again in the real product and environment. Performance can sneak up on you.

Comment: You shouldn't be allowing performance concerns to govern your decision when choosing stack/heap.

Comment: Depends on the system I guess.  Some embedded type systems have "faster" RAM for the stack and may see an advantage.  Makes local thread storage a bit easier I guess as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If there is any it is negligible. However the one thing you should keep in mind is that the **actual allocation** process is slower for heap than the stack. 
That is

```
vector<T> t;
```

is faster than

```
vector<T>* t = new vector<T>;
```

Since allocating on the stack basically involves just moving the stack pointer.

So all life time issues aside, if you have to allocate **a lot of vectors** you might build up on that small performance loss.

However if you have **few vectors** then in my opinion there will be no significant gain.

I should mention that worrying about the performance gains from stack and heap allocation fails under [**premature optimization**](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?PrematureOptimization). So just chose which ever fits your needs better and use that. It would rather pay off to focus on optimizing your algorithms.

> Programmers waste enormous amounts of time thinking about, or worrying
>   about, the speed of noncritical parts of their programs, and these
>   attempts at efficiency actually have a strong negative impact when
>   debugging and maintenance are considered. We should forget about small
>   efficiencies, say about 97% of the time: premature optimization is the
>   root of all evil. Yet we should not pass up our opportunities in that
>   critical 3%."

Comment: +1 - Optimization decisions should be based on profiled evidence.

Comment: Re: premature optimization: the primary reason for choosing stack versus heap is object lifetime. Performance is secondary, and hacking to fix lifetimes of objects that have been deliberately misplaced makes code brittle.

Comment: I think you could have stopped at the word "negligible" and had a completely correct answer. The number of vectors you would have to allocate to make a noticeable difference is impractical, and each vector would have to be empty or nearly so.

Comment: @MarkRansom Does it matter if the vector is empty? Since this doesn't worry about what is in it instead about creating the actual structure of the vector. No? (the data is always on heap anyways.)

Comment: It's just a matter of proportion. If the vectors aren't empty you would expect the allocations and object initializations to take much longer than the allocation of the vector object itself, making the overall effect negligible again.

Answer (score 1):

In theory, it's probably a tiny bit faster to create the vector as a local variable instead of (for example) having a pointer to a vector as the local variable, and the vector itself allocated dynamically. The latter requires an extra level of indirection to get to the data you really care about.

In reality, the difference will almost always be *far* too small to notice or care about. Unless you really need to allocate it dynamically, you generally want to create a vector as a local variable, but the micro-optimization of avoiding an extra level of indirection is probably the *least* of the reasons to do so. Keeping your code simple, understandable, and dependable are *much* better reasons.